# How to add tooltip to angular formly dropdown elements

Tags: angular, tooltip, dropdown, angular-formly, ngx-formly

I want to add tooltip to angular formly dropdown element, is there a way to solve this?

Tool tip should contain label - value of the dropdown elements.
Is there any tooltip property which we can use under prop of formly field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `title` property to achieve this by putting it in the `option` tag:

```
<select>
  <option title="Lorem" value="Lorem">Lorem</value>
  <option value="Ipsum">Ipsum</value>
</select>
```

For a more "stylish" way to achieve this, you can have a look at the [MatTooltip](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview)